# MVVM: how to notify the change of every object property when I change the object itself?

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a ViewModel that contains a `(Person)Patient` property. In my View, I bind to some of the properties of `Patient`, say, `Name` and `Age`.

The problem is: if I change Patient, nothing happens in my view, unless I explicitly notify of each property change (I am using `Caliburn.Micro` thus the `PropertyChangedBase`and `NotifyOfPropertyChange` stuff):

```
public class PersonViewModel : PropertyChangedBase {

    Person _patient;

    public Person Patient {
        get { return _patient; }
        set {
            _patient = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Patient); // this doesn't update the view
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name); // this updates, but would I need one line for each property??
        }
    }
}
```

The broader application context is this: I have a PersonManager screen, with three regions, each with their view and viewmodel: a list of persons, the information of a single person, and the list of medical procedures associated with each person.

I am almost sure I am missing something here. I would like to select a person in the person list, and then the regions showing person data and person procedures would update via binding, without having to manually notify each property change of the newly selected person.

Comment: I'm not sure your illustrated code is a code-smell, and what you've typed (about many properties) doesn't seem to add-up to the code example you've posted. You have a sub-viewmodel which contains a reference to a `Person`. You also have a `CurrentPerson` on the parent viewmodel. When the parent viewmodel `Person` changes, you need to ensure that all sub-viewmodels get updated with the change, otherwise their properties are still pointing to the old person object. An alternative is to bind the first view directly to the second view in your consolidated VM (in the XAML)..

Comment: @Charleh actually there is a small inconsistency in my posted code. I actually solved the problem with a somewhat esoteric (IMO) feature of INPC, which I will post as an answer now.

Answer (score 8):

I have solved the problem using a [feature of `PropertyChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx), which is using `null` as a parameter:

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object
>   have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name
>   in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

Then, I solved my problem with:

```
    public Paciente Paciente {
        get { return _paciente; }
        set {
            _paciente = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(null);
        }
    }
```

and it worked!